# How to show timezone with country and city name in list in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timezone, timezone-offset

I am developing an application where i have to show the timezone with country and city name in `spinner`. I have use `TimeZone` class for it. But in this case i am getting a `timezoneId` and `timezoneName` only. How i can show timezone with country and city name in `spinner` ?

Comment: See this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName() and this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone#getAvailableIDs(int)

Comment: Time zones are usually given with *region* (continent or ocean) and city (or island (group)), as for example America/Adak, Asia/Bangkok, Atlantic/Canary, Indian/Mahe. Would this be fine with you?

Comment: @OleV.V. i want to show the timezone like Calcutta (India), Berlin (Germany) but in my case it show like "Europe/Berlin" . I didn't get the county name here. Is there any api or library which shows show timezone with country and city name in list ?

Comment: @crammeur i have checked the documentation. But it couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: I don’t know of such an API, but one might exist. You basically need a database of towns and countries, I guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:-

```
private String[] timezoneArray;
private Spinner spinner_timezone;

spinner_timezone = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_timezone);
```

Then call this

```
 timezoneArray = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), timezoneArray);
        spinner_timezone.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < timezoneArray.length; i++) {
            if (timezoneArray[i].equals(TimeZone.getDefault().getID())) {
                spinner_timezone.setSelection(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

then `CustomAdapter` class

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        String[] countryNames;
        LayoutInflater inflter;

        public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] countryNames) {
            this.context = applicationContext;
            this.countryNames = countryNames;
            inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return countryNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
            TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            names.setText(displayTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(countryNames[i])));
            return view;
        }

        private String displayTimeZone(TimeZone tz) {

            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tz.getRawOffset());
            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tz.getRawOffset())
                    - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
            // avoid -4:-30 issue
            minutes = Math.abs(minutes);

            String result = "";
            if (hours > 0) {
                result = String.format("(GMT +%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
            } else {
                result = String.format("(GMT %d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
            }

            return result;

        }
    }
```

And custom_spinner_items here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Wifi Airtel"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It hardly gives the time zones in the format Calcutta (India) or Berlin (Germany) as requested by the asker in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667693/how-to-show-timezone-with-country-and-city-name-in-list-in-android#comment90362339_51667693). Also it uses the long outdated and poorly designed `TimeZone` class. Its modern replacement is the `ZoneId` class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: I appreciate your experience , you can update the answer or post new answer for it dear :) , i will check it too

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? it provides a `DateTimeUtils.getDefaultTimeZoneNames()` method which returns a map of Time zone names.

You can find more information [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#getDefaultTimeZoneNames--)

Comment: If you’re ready to accept an external library — which could have great benefits, I agree — why not go for the successor of Joda-Time? java.time has been backported and the backport adapted for Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/build.gradle). On a new Android (API level 26 or higher) java.time is even built in and no external library needed.

Comment: @OleV.V. I was just suggesting Joda Time because that's the one I know, but I will take a look to ThreeTenABP, thanks!